# R: How to use current function output's within this function

Tags: r, function

I write a R function using `if & else if` in it. See the code below:

```
i_ti_12 <- function(x){
  if (x <= 44)
  {ti = exp(-13.2238 + 0.152568*x)}
  else if (x >= 49)
  {ti = -0.01245109 + 0.000315605*x}
  else (x > 44 & x < 49)
  {ti = (x-44)*(i_ti_12(49))/(49-44) + (49-x)*(i_ti_12(44))/(49-44)}
  return(ti)
}
```

I want to use this function's output, `i_ti_12(49)` within this function, but the above code doesn't work. The output is:

```
> i_ti_12(49)
Error: C stack usage  7974292 is too close to the limit
```

The simple solution is just replace `i_ti_12(49)` by `-0.01245109 + 0.000315605*49`, but its not a clear way to solve it and might not work in complex cases.

So I really want to know and to learn if there are clear methods to do this? I mean, like above simple example, write a conditional function using one condition's output in this function. Any help is highly appreciate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your last `else` is followed by a condition `(x > 44 & x < 49)`, which actually is not correct. If you have `(x > 44 & x < 49)` there, that means you will execute that statement, and `ti = (x-44)*(i_ti_12(49))/(49-44) + (49-x)*(i_ti_12(44))/(49-44)` is something independent with your `if-else` structure.

In that case, when you call `i_ti_12(49)`, your function does not know when the recursion should be terminated since you did not define that case.

You can try the code below:

```
i_ti_12 <- function(x){
  if (x <= 44)
  {ti = exp(-13.2238 + 0.152568*x)}
  else if (x >= 49)
  {ti = -0.01245109 + 0.000315605*x}
  else
  {ti = (x-44)*(i_ti_12(49))/(49-44) + (49-x)*(i_ti_12(44))/(49-44)}
  return(ti)
}
```

such that

```
> i_ti_12(49)
[1] 0.003013555
```

Comment: Wow! It works! Could you explain why it works after removing the final condition?

Comment: @Hillary see some of my explanation, hope it is helpful

Comment: @ThomaslsCoding This makes sense! Thanks a lot! Do you know why R function is so clear that it can recognize its conditional output? In this case, does R function  run the first condition and save the `return(ti)` and then run the second condition and save the corresponding return, and then to the third condition?

Comment: @Hillary the statement is executed as long as the corresponding condition is met, and then exits `if-else` control flow  and moves to `return(ti)`